# A multifractal model of asset returns - Mandelbrot, scaling result

Tags: pr.probability

I am looking at the paper in the title and I am trying to derive their result in equation $2$. Here is what I obtain. Start with:

$$X(ct) \stackrel{d}{=} M(c)X(t)$$

where $M(.)$ and $X(.)$ are random independent functions of parameters $c$ and $t$. Set $f(t) = ct$, then $f(c^{-1}t)=t$, then

$$X(f(t)) \stackrel{d}{=}M(c)X(f(c^{-1}t))$$, moving along the time axis such that the second term is $t+\Delta t$, we have

$$X(t+f(\Delta t)) \stackrel{d}{=}M(c)X(t+f(c^{-1}\Delta t))$$

or

$$X(t+c\Delta t) \stackrel{d}{=} M(c) X(t+\Delta t)$$

Now subtracting $X(t)$ from both sides:

$$X(t+c\Delta t)  - X(t) \stackrel{d}{=} M(c) X(t+\Delta t) - X(t)$$

But the result in the paper is:

$$X(t+c\Delta t)  - X(t) \stackrel{d}{=} M(c)(X(t+\Delta t) - X(t))$$

Comment: equation 2 is not a consequence of equation 1 in [Mandelbrot's paper](http://users.math.yale.edu/~bbm3/web_pdfs/Cowles1164.pdf), it's a definition of a separate class of processes

Comment: is it a definition then? thank you

Comment: I believe it refers to equality in distribution in this case